# How to flow layout list group items in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Using the example from http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

This only gives me a tall thin column, how do I wrap on boundaries? Like text in a paragraph does?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a surrounding div (called main-list in the code below) and see if it works. Here is a working example via [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7uon0dw/1/).

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .main-list {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-list>li {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this class to your css file :

```
.scrollFlow{
 **height:250px; //for example
 overflow:scroll;**
}
```

and then add this class to ul element like this :

```
<ul class="list-group **scrollFlow**">
```